# Hive Table Creation Using MongoDB Hadoop Driver

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive, mongodb-hadoop

I am trying to connect from a Hive Database to a collection in MongoDB using a driver (jars) provided on the wiki site. Here are the steps I did: -

I created a collection in MongoDB called "Diamond" under a database called "Moe" and it has got 20 documents:

I wanted to connect from Hive via the Hadoop MongoDB Driver and view these documents via Hive.

I have both MongoDB and Hive installed on the same server and configured. However I don't see any variable called the HIVE_CLASPATH I wonder where that is.

```
So I installed 3 divers on the server: -
mongo-hadoop-core-1.5.2.jar;
mongo-hadoop-hive-1.5.2.jar;
mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar;
```

Now, I connect to Hive, and then add these 2 jar's to my classpath by the following commands: - (they get added successfully)

```
add jar /hadoopgdc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/mongo-hadoop-hive-1.5.2.jar;
add jar /hadoopgdc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/mongo-hadoop-core-1.5.2.jar;
add jar /hadoopgdc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar;
```

Now I create a table in HIVE: -

```
CREATE TABLE Diamond
(
carat    DOUBLE,
cut      STRING,
color    STRING,
clarity  STRING,
depth    DOUBLE,
table    DOUBLE,
price    DOUBLE,
xcord    DOUBLE,
ycord    DOUBLE,
zcord    DOUBLE
)
STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"carat":"carat","cut":"cut",                 
"color":"color", "clarity":"clarity", "depth":"depth", "table":"table", 
"price":"price", "xcord":"x", "ycord":"y", "zcord":"z"}')
TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://localhost:27017/Moe.Diamond');


However when I execute the above command in Hive I get the error below: -

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/util/JSON
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.BSONSerDe.initialize(BSONSerDe.java:110)
    at     org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.util.JSON
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 23 more
    FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from 
   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

I have tried the following: -
- placing the jars in every possible directory with no effect
- The class that is supposed to be missing, is pretty much present in the jar file. 
- oh yes and the MongoStorageHandler class is very much in the jar.

I am done breaking my head with this !! If anyone can shed some light on what I could do to alleviate my anxiety, it would be great.

Thanks again.
Mario

Answer (score -1):

I identified what the issue was. To connect from HIVE to MongoDB, the MongoDb Driver uses invokes a java class in a hive jar library 
**

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.PreExecutePrinter

**
Now this class is supposed to be found in the jar file - hive-exec-0.11.0.1.3.2.0-111.jar. However it is available only in more recent versions of HIVE and not older ones.

It is not available in 0.11.0.1.3.2.0-111 but is visibly detectable in 0.13.0.2.1.7.0-784.

The solution here was to connect to a version of HIVE that is supported by the driver. MongoDB does state that its driver supports a certain version of Hadoop, but doesn't drill down to the individual Application (HIVE / SQOOP).